# Perform port listening during service lifetime

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm a beginer in WCF. I need to listen to a specific port in my service. Listening should be started when service is hosted (as Windows Service). It should be stopped when the service is stopped.

I've managed to implement listening in simple console application in endless loop.

Is there any way to do it in service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a thread when the service starts that does the port listening, by assumption I assume you know how to do the port listening. Then when the service ends call the Thread.Abort method of the listener thread. Remember to catch ThreadAbortException in the thread as this exception is raised when the thread gets killed. You will need to do cleanup here such as closing the port and any stream readers/writers.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be a problem, you will just need to host it as a windows service. The port should be defined as part of the endpoint address. For more information follow this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069(v=vs.90).aspx